# "Compound Literals" as an Argument

Tags: c, function-parameter, compound-literals

Calling the function `sum(int [], arr_size)` in the statement

```
total = sum((int []){1,2,3,4,5}, 5);
```

a  **Compound Literal** `(int []){1,2,3,4,5}` is passed as argument. It is clear that the length of array is determined by numbers of elements in literal(which is of-course `5` here). Then what is the need of passing `5` as another argument?

can't we define above function as

```
sum(int []) {....}
```

and then calling it as

```
total = sum((int []){1,2,3,4,5})
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `sum` that way and call it as shown in your example, but in that case you will not be able to determine the size of the array inside the function.

What you could do is declare `sum` as

```
int sum(int (*a)[5]) 
{
  ...
}
```

and then call it as

```
total = sum(&(int []){1,2,3,4,5});
```

But in this case you will be restricted to arrays of size `5` only. If you want to have a function that works with arrays of any size, you have to either pass the size from outside or reserve some sort of "terminator" element in your array

Comment: Got it man! You fixed the size of array in function definition and that's why you are not passing the size,right?

Comment: @haccks: Yes. So your options are either fix the size or pass the size separately. Also note that in my version the array is passed through "pointer-to-array" parameter. This is why there's an `&` in the call. And inside the function the array must be accessed as `(*a)[i]`, not as `a[i]`.

Comment: @haccks: Just about any time you're dealing with arrays, you have to use pointers. Suggested reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @KeithThompson; Thanks for the link sir. Actually this chapter `Arrays` is given before `pointers` in the book I am reading from and i am on `Arrays` that's why i am afraid of pointers.

Comment: @haccks: You can do a fair amount of stuff with arrays without *explicitly* using pointers, or knowing about them. But using array expressions as function arguments probably shouldn't be one of them -- as you've seen.

Answer (score 9):

Your function `sum` is identical to `sum(int *, size_t)`; the square brackets are just syntactic sugar. No arrays are passed at any point, and indeed you *cannot* pass arrays as function arguments in C. Thus there is no size information left in the "array" part of the function parameters, and the size must be passed separately.

Comment: Here `compound literal` is used as argument.

Comment: @haccks: But there are still no array function *parameters*. The compound literal decays to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @qwwqwwq: That's incorrect. The `(int [])` is not a cast, it's part of the syntax of a compound literal. The operand of a cast is either an expression or a parenthesized type name; `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` is neither. The expression `(int []){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` is of array type, specifically `int[5]`. It's implicitly converted to `int*` because *all* expressions of array type are converted to pointers, with three exceptions that don't apply here.